# how to make NSString which is NULL

Tags: ios

I get data from server, however,`NSString` is `NULL` in some cases, I don't know why `NSString` is NULL, how to make a `NSString` with NULL?

Comment: Sample data would be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like the server is responding no data

Comment: will suggest to create a string with no characters

Comment: can you please describe the problem in more details?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the string is not `NULL`.

First of all, in Objective C, you should use `nil` instead of `NULL`.

Another thing is, you cannot have `nil` in iOS containers (`NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, etc.).
But, some API needs to set an empty value for a key.

To fix this problem, Apple introduced the `NSNull` class (and singleton).

So, to check if the data is empty, you must compare the value with the `NSNull` singleton, like this :

```
id data = yourDictionary[@"yourKey"];
if (data == [NSNull null]) {
    // Data is invalid, and calling any message on it will result in a crash
} else {
    // Place your data in the any kind of container. You can even use isKindOfClass to be sure.
    NSString * string = data;
}
```

Comment: How is my answer different from this answer ?

Comment: I'm just trying to help him. With your way, it would have worked, but he wouldn't have any idea what he is doing. I hope that with my answer, he will be able to understand what's happening, instead of using a macro he doesn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following macros

```
#define IsNULL(original) original == (id)[NSNull null]

#define IfNULL(original, replacement) IsNULL(original) ? replacement : original

#define SafeString(value) IfNULL(value, @"")
```

And then use

```
NSLog("%@",SafeString(YOURSTRING));
```

Comment: Any reason for the Downvote? You can try to improve the answer..

Comment: Not my downvote but how can you use IsNULL before you define it?  Also OP says it is `NULL` not `NSNull`.

Comment: It just an example, it can be obviously corrected, and other comparisons can be added.. I am correcting the sequence though..